# Sendgrid Dark Mode compatibility with two logos

Tags: html, css, sendgrid

I'm working with Sendgrid, but it has conflicts with the logo in dark mode, my logo is black and I don't want to add a white border to the letters. I have two logos, one black and one white. I need to detect on all devices when it is in dark mode and when it is not.

On my `head` html I have:

```
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
<meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark">
```

In the css styles I have this:

```
    .dark-block { display: none; }
    .dark-logo { display: none; }
    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark ) {
      .dark-logo { display:inline !important; line-height: auto !important; }
      .light-logo { display:none; display:none !important; }
      .light-block { display:none; }
      .dark-block { display:block; }
      
      body, p, a, td {
          color: #FFFFFF !important;
      }
    }
```

Then in my html I have the two logos with the class `dark-logo / light-log`.
but on iPhone it doesn't work, I have tried Outlook dark mode in Chrome and it works perfectly, on Android Outlook it doesn't work.

I need help to know how to correctly identify if the theme is in dark or light mode.

I appreciate the help. Thank you!

Comment: I even tried converting the image to svg and adding the style `fill` with black and the theme will take care of adding the correct color, but the svg is not showing in the email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found compatibility for all devices is to do the logo recommendation by sendgrid [image]

Adding a white border when `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark )` doesn't work.